# Autowired annotation in Servlet Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, annotations

I have problem (when i'm calling method from another component class) with `NullPointerException` like this:

```
ERROR [UploadServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet UploadServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.crai.servlets.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:77)
    at pl.crai.servlets.FileUploadServlet.handleRequest(FileUploadServlet.java:286)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.service(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
```

My spring version is 3.2 and it's my servlet class injection:

```
@Component
public class FileUploadServlet implements HttpRequestHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MessagesPersistence messagesPersistence;
```

Next, my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean name="UploadServlet" class="pl.crai.servlets.FileUploadServlet">

    </bean>
```

spring-servlet.xml :

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <import resource="applicationContext.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.crai" />
```

and entire `web.xml`:

```
<display-name></display-name>

    <listener>
      <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
   </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping >

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>downloadAttachments</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pl.crai.servlets.DownloadAttachmentsSerlvet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>downloadAttachments</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/downFile/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>downloadMultipleAttachments</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pl.crai.servlets.DownloadMultipleAttachmentsServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>downloadMultipleAttachments</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/downMultipleFile/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


     <servlet>
    <display-name>UploadServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet

    </servlet-class>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/uploadFile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>pl.crai.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I tried to try use different settings (without `@Component`annatotion in servlet, with `@Component("UploadServlet")`, without config in xml files, and more..)
Please help!

======================EDIT====================================

So.. when I removed  `<import resource= from spring-servlet.xml` autowired in another component in my project doesn't work.

My uprgade version of web.xml is:

```
<display-name></display-name>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
   </listener>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping >

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>downloadAttachments</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pl.crai.servlets.DownloadAttachmentsSerlvet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>downloadAttachments</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/downFile/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>downloadMultipleAttachments</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pl.crai.servlets.DownloadMultipleAttachmentsServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>downloadMultipleAttachments</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/downMultipleFile/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


     <servlet>
    <display-name>UploadServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet
           <!-- org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet --> 
    </servlet-class>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/uploadFile</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>pl.crai.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

But it still doesn't work with another exception:

```
Allocate exception for servlet UploadServlet
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'UploadServlet' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.init(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:211)
```

Comment: Have you set up the Spring `ContextLoaderListener` with appropriate `contextConfigLocation`?

Comment: when you get exception exactly? is your injection failed or action?

Comment: I get exception when action.

Comment: Can you show your entire web.xml?

Comment: Ok, all from web.xml is in first post :)

Answer (score -1):

Your `UploadServlet` should be defined in your root web application context (the one loaded up by `ContextLoaderListener`):

So the changes should be, add the bean to your applicationContext.xml file, which you have already done.
Remove `<import resource..` from your `servlet-context.xml` file
Load up applicationContext.xml instead through `ContextLoaderListener`, NOT through `<import resource...`, so in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I must answer in first post

Comment: I checked your Edit..you seem to have done everything that is required, strange that it still does not work. Are you not seeing any exceptions at startup? Is it possible for you to place a stripped down project in github?